# Как правильно реализовать именованные кортежи

Tags: python, tuple

Ревьюером было предложено использованием именованных кортежей для читабельности кода. Почитал [статью](https://habr.com/ru/post/330034/) посмотрел видео в ютубе, но пока трудно с пониманием реализацией.
Я так понимаю в моем случае его надо прописывать в методе transformations, и первое что я должен создать класс и его атрибуты. Например Competitors = namedtuple('Competitors', 'name pi fi'), а дальше я должен через созданную переменную Competitors создать экземпляры класса переданные в метод transformations. А как это сделать туплю и не могу понять что делать.

В метод tranformations передается кортеж с такими данными (<имя>, <числовое значение>, <числовое значение>) и возвращает тот же кортеж только в другом порядке.

```
def partition(competitors, left, right):
    if right <= left:
        return
    pivot = (left + right) // 2
    part = competitors[pivot]
    begin = left
    end = right
    while begin <= end:
        while part > competitors[begin]:
            begin += 1
        while part < competitors[end]:
            end -= 1
        if begin <= end:
            competitors[begin], competitors[end] = competitors[
                end], competitors[begin]
            begin += 1
            end -= 1
    partition(competitors, left, end)
    partition(competitors, begin, right)


def transformations(competitors):
    competitors[1] = - int(competitors[1])
    competitors[2] = int(competitors[2])
    return [competitors[1], competitors[2], competitors[0]]


def quick_sort(competitors):
    partition(competitors, 0, len(competitors) - 1)
    return [line[2] for line in competitors]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    number = int(input())
    competitors = [transformations(input().split()) for _ in range(number)]
    result = quick_sort(competitors)
    print(*result, sep="\n")
```

Comment: В методе `transformations` все эти `competitors[1]` и `[competitors[1], competitors[2], competitors[0]]` - непонятно что там внутри и что в итоге. Поэтому вместо получения и возврата массива с индексами (которые ничего не означают для читателя) вы можете заменить их на словарь или классы (кортежи), у которых есть имена и код станет более читабельный. И не стоит забывать про типизированный способ создания кортежей через `from typing import NamedTuple`

Comment: `В метод tranformations передается кортеж с такими данными (<имя>, <числовое значение>, <числовое значение>) и возвращает тот же кортеж только в другом порядке.` - судя по тому, что вы в этой функции перезаписываете элементы competitors, то вы явно туда не кортеж передаете, а скорее всего список. На выходе почему-то первый элемент (имя?) оказывается последним. Если менять на namedtuple, то нужно быть готовым к тому, что это неизменяемая структура данных. Ну или вам на самом деле нужен класс (или датакласс), а не namedtuple.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде не хватает читабельности. Что такое `line[2]`? что там лежит?
Числа-индексы читателю (да и писателю тоже) ни о чем не говорят. Должны быть говорящие ключи. Теоретически может подойти словарь, namedtuple, класс (dataclass).

Словарь сразу плох - мутабельный и IDE не дает подсказки.
В остальном - вопрос не про выбор, раз namedtuple, значит namedtuple

Заводим `namedtuple` (возьмем из `collections`, вы же используете его, а не из модуля `typing`)

```
Competitor = namedtuple('Competitor', 'login number fine')
```

и пусть `transformations` станет более читабельным. Вроде такого, я могу ошибаться, мне не хочется вчитываться что под индексами должно быть.

```
def transformations(competitor_data: list[str]) -> Competitor:
    assert len(competitor_data) == 3
    login, num, fine = competitor_data
    return Competitor(login, -int(num), int(fine))
```

делать `competitor_data` как кортеж - имхо польза сомнительная, ведь по факту метод парсит сырой ввод в кортежи.

далее мы работаем уже с объектом `Competitor`, а значит улучшаем читабельность метода `quick_sort`

```
def quick_sort(competitors: list[Competitor]) -> list[str]:
    partition(competitors, 0, len(competitors) - 1)
    return [competitor.login for competitor in competitors]
```

сразу понятно, что возвращается список логинов, а не непонятный `line[2]` (опустим деталь, что этот метод вообще не должен возвращать логины, а только сортировать)

Метод `partition`. Там используются операции сравнения и там без 0.5 не разберешься как и что сравнивается.
Я как-то не вижу смысла сравнения "в лоб" и ожидал бы что сравнивается по какому-нибудь полю,  например fine, но модифицировать `partition` для сравнения явных полей некрасиво. Лучше определить свои операции сравнения в `Competitor` - пусть сравнивает по полю `fine`

Поскольку это `namedtuple` из `collections`, то в нем нельзя определить методы сравнения прямо, но можно так

```
class Competitor(namedtuple('Competitor', 'login number fine')):
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.fine > other.fine

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.fine < other.fine

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.fine == other.fine
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так я реализовал метод transformations

```
from collections import namedtuple

...

def transformations(competitors):
    Competitor = namedtuple('Competitor', 'login number fine')
    participant = Competitor(
        competitors[0], - int(competitors[1]), int(competitors[2])
    )
    return participant.number, participant.fine, participant.login
```

Но время выполнения на некоторых тестах при этом увеличилось почти в 3 раза.

Comment: `Competitor = namedtuple` вынесите наружу. Он должен быть один раз. А в остальном - вместо `return participant.number, participant.fine, participant.login` вы должны `return participant` и далее по всему коду у вас ходит кортеж, а не список и все ваши `line[2]` превратятся в понятные line.login (хотя имя line тут само по себе не подходит)